# ¿Que hacer cuando hay una respuesta aceptada y valorada que genera desinformación?

Tags: discusión, votos, respuesta, respuesta-aceptada

Hace poco encontré una pregunta sobre consultas SQL usando PHP aquí: [SELECT no funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84172/select-no-funciona/84204#84204)

La verdad rápidamente la comunidad se procuro en responder, así que no hice por facilitar una respuesta pensando que más temprano que tarde encontrarían solución y darle oportunidad de participación a otros, basado en lo popularidad de la pregunta.

Sin embargo cuando veo las respuestas, noté que erróneamente las respuestas asumen que el error es debido a el entrecomillado en PHP, cosa que no es cierta. Aún así, una de estas es seleccionada como aceptada, posiblemente a raíz de copiar y pegar la respuesta, puesto que el error muy posiblemente es de tipeo en en el nombre de uno de los campos de las tablas presentadas.

Hice una contribución, solo para informar lo erróneo de la apreciación, posterior a haber comentado sobre una de las respuestas mejor valoradas. La verdad no tengo problema en eliminar la contribución, si la  respuesta mejor punteada verificara la información que expone. Pero ¿Qué hacer si no lo hace?

Comment: Si tu respuesta es correcta (que me imagino que lo es), realmente es un error tipográfico y la pregunta debería ser cerrada directamente.

Comment: Creo que no tengo privilegios para votar en pro de cerrar alguna pregunta, supongo que será gestión de los usuarios con mayor reputación.

Comment: Tampoco está de más dejar un comentario indicando al OP que no tiene mucho sentido aceptar una respuesta si no resolvió su problema. Una vez aceptada, aparecerá la primera por los siglos de los siglos y eso puede crear confusión. Tampoco es descabellado editar la respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 13):

Usa tus votos. Si al OP le sirvió lo que tu consideras una mala respuesta, es problema del OP. Pero los usuarios del futuro ven las respuestas ordenadas por votos, y ahí no decide el OP sino la comunidad.

Comment: Bien explicado. La pena es que la respuesta aceptada siempre aparecerá primera :/

Comment: @fedorqui sería una característica interesante del sitio que, cuando se selecciona la respuesta aceptada, ésta posea una nota que diga algo como: _recuerda que esta respuesta fue útil para el OP, pero si esta pregunta no resuelve tu problema, lee detenidamente las otras respuestas o publica una nueva pregunta._

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave absolutamente. Yo ya he cogido la costumbre de mirar la siguiente respuesta después de la aceptada, para ver si tienes más votos. Sin embargo, cuando veo a gente utilizando [so] me doy cuenta que nunca lo hacen tomando la idea de que la primera respuesta es siempre "la buena". Yo implementaría algo así como: si la respuesta aceptada tiene alguna que compite seriamente con ella, añade un texto del tipo que mencionas. "Compite" para mí sería algo así como que tiene mayor puntuación y es posterior.